# Break Wine Glass Using Mathematica

Tags: sound

I will be running a demonstration for high school students in a couple of weeks.  I’m hoping to introduce them to differential equations by using mathematics to generate a sound wave to break a wine glass.  I have a loud powered speaker I can connect to the audio out of my computer.

I’d like to use Mathematica to generate the sound wave using the Manipulate function to vary the frequency of the sound wave to reach the resonant frequency of the glass so that we can break it. I would be nice to see the standing wave in Mathematica too so they can see the frequency changing as well as hearing it.

Is this possible using a Mathematica?  If so, can you point me in the right direction?  I have had zero luck using manipulate to vary the frequency of the audio output.

Comment: Is this helpful https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20984/using-manipulate-to-vary-the-frequency-of-a-sound-produced-by-soundnote?

Comment: What have you tried? The community [expects the following](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) from you: 
✅: A clear description of an on-topic problem or goal.
❌: A minimal working *Wolfram Language* code example, formatted, easy to *copy&paste*, in [Raw InputForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/RawInputForm.html). 
❌. An example of what you expect as output.
❌. Some proof of minimal *Mathematica* knowledge. 
❌. Minimum due diligence: Share how you have searched the site and documentation, your attempts and reasons to believe an answer exists.

Comment: These help a lot. I should be able to make this work for my application.

Comment: @Bflat Could you start this topic on https://physics.stackexchange.com/ ? Please, refer to this page https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214279/3d-elastic-waves-in-a-glass