# Dynamic sound generator

Tags: dynamic, sound

i wanna create a notebook with dynamic sound-output. I want to emit a continous sound (sine wave) while being able to adjust the frequency in real time without having to click the play-button again. 
Something like

```
    Sound[Play[Sin[2*Pi*Dynamic[f]*t], {t, 0, 10}]]
```

doesnt work (and im not surprised about that...).

Anyone got an idea?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you, but that doesnt really solve my problem. I want to, for example by using a slider, to alternate the frequency while the sound is still playing and it would alter its frequency dynamically and smoothly. Similar to this: http://www.szynalski.com/tone-generator/ With your code i still have to click the play-button and also have to wait for 10 seconds until the current sound is finished.

Comment: And also this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13656/12  The short answer is that this is not really possible. Mathematica is not meant for real-time processing.  You could hack something together by playing short pieces of sounds in a loop, but they won't be seamless. I expect such a solution to be practically unusable.